# Is there a complete canonical example of a asp.net web api implementation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

The webapi implementations I'm finding are very different, and I was wondering if there was a project that shows all of the capabilities of webapi done the "right way".

Comment: There isn't one right way

Comment: Is there an opinionated example that handles most generic use cases?